# Probability of repeating dice

Tags: probability, dice

> Three fair 6−sided dice are rolled and their upfaces are recorded.
> Find the probability that the values showing upon rolling all three
> dice again is the same as the original three values recorded.

Let $X_1$, $X_2$ and $X_3$ be the three first rolls. We observe $X_1=x$, $X_2=y$ and $X_3=z$ and we are interested in $$P\bigg((X_4, X_5,X_6) \in \sigma(x,y,z) | X_1=x,X_2=y, X_3=z\bigg) $$

Meaning that if we observe $(X_1,X_2,X_3)=(1,2,4)$ we want $(X_4, X_5,X_6)$ to be in the set of permutations of $(x,y,z)$ for example $(2,4,1)$ would be fine, right?

Now I feel that the answer depends on $x,y,z$ because if $x=y=z$ the probability we are looking for is  $1/6^3=1/216$. If $x\neq y\neq z$ then that probability is now $6/6^3=1/36$ because there are 6 possible combinations.

I wanted to condition on the fact that numbers of three first rolls could be repeated or not but it gets messier, is there a way out?

Comment: This seems like a tedious case by case thing.  $XXX, XXY, XYZ$.  It's only three cases, so not all that tedious.

Comment: @lulu I have no problem doing tedious stuff but won't the answer be a function of $x,y,z$ which I believe is an issue

Comment: No, it won't be.  $335$ is exactly as probable as $442$, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments above, there are 3 cases to take care of here:

1. All die rolls are different
2. 2 die rolls are the same
3. All die rolls are the same

Let's deal with case 1 first.
If all 3 rolls are different then the first die roll has a $\frac{3}{6}$ chance of being one that we need, the second a $\frac{2}{6}$ and then the last a $\frac{1}{6}$ chance. Multiply these out and do some simplification to get $\frac{1}{36}$.

Your original question wanted to condition this on the fact that they were all different so if we are doing that then the probability is simply $\frac{1}{36}$ as shown above.

Now, let's do the second case. The first roll always has a $\frac{2}{6}$ chance of being one that we need and the last one is always $\frac{1}{6}$ but the second one's probability is based on whether or not the first one was the one that occurred once or twice which means our equation is $\frac{2}{6}\frac{1}{6}(\frac{2}{3}\frac{2}{6} + \frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{6}) = \frac{5}{324}$.

As already pointed out, the probability for the third case is $\frac{1}{216}$.

Now let's find the total probability of this happening without the conditioning:

$\frac{4}{6}\frac{5}{6}\frac{1}{36} + $
$(\frac{1}{6}\frac{5}{6} + \frac{5}{6}\frac{2}{6})\frac{5}{324} +$
$\frac{1}{216}^2$

Which gives us (assuming I did not simplify incorrectly lol) a probability of $\frac{1021}{46656}\approx0.02188$